# AWS Cognito: Trigger the MFA if the user is already logged in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to trigger a MFA check if the user is already logged in with Cognito ? and so get a new token if successful ?

I can't ask for his password.

Thank you.

Comment: Also wondering about this, got any luck or solution?